# XCode debugger sucks; alternatives?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos

I've been programming on the Mac since I was a little kid using THINK C. I've never had to use a debugger as bad as the one that comes with XCode.

- It's unresponsive, and bogs down further and becomes unstable when watching more variables.
- When it crashes, I lose undo history for my sources because it's integrated with the editor.
- It doesn't benefit from integration, though, as the source viewer is unusable for stepping: Trying to select a line by clicking on the left margin makes a button appear from nowhere which causes to program to *continue* to that line, in the editor window, which shouldn't relate to debugging in the first place. Horrible UI and horrible implementation.
- A hobbled pretty-data "summary" syntax which can't send an object to the Expressions window.
- he Expressions window isn't aware of any kind of context, ever.
- Can't select a particular thread to debug, far as I can tell, and doesn't jump to the thread that called abort().

The *kernel* debugger for *Mac OS 9* was better than this. It's time to give up.

What standalone front-ends for GDB work on OS X? I found http://ddd.darwinports.com/ but it's hard to find praise or anecdotes for it, or other alternatives.

Support for STL containers is a big plus for me. I couldn't care less about Objective-C or Apple-anything.

Comment: What do you want, visual studios on the mac? You'll have the same problems writing GCC/GDB on x86.

Comment: Some of the Xcode shortcomings can be alleviated if you're willing to use the gdb console directly. For example, dumping long NSStrings can be done with

p (void)CFShow(MyString)

in the console.

Comment: +1 for THINK C! (I liked THINK Pascal's debugger better though).

Comment: Couldn't you just shorten that question to "What alternative GUIs are there for gdb on Mac OS X?"

Comment: @Mr-sk: One thing Microsoft has always seemed to get right was the debugger in Visual Studio. As long as I can remember (VC1.5) it has always been awesome. Almost as good as THINK Pascal's debugger :P

Comment: @Seva: I often use the console, but it seems unsuitable for rapidly stepping and watching a large number of objects interact. @gs: Maybe, but that's longer than my phrasing ;v) also, non-GDB alternatives are possible. @Seth: I get the impression that Apple's testing strategy isn't keeping up with "development", ie bloat. I'm a little afraid of using an unpopular debugger because quality depends on testing intensity…

Comment: It's ridicolously non-standard and I get errors for assigning an enum to int, it doesn't recognize functions, etc.. pathetic.

Answer (score 2):

I tend to use valgrind for memory related errors; 
gdb (in a teminal) when I want a backtrace;
and logging + couts for all else (if it's not crashing, and there's no memory corruption, the bug seems easier).

Admittedtely, no idea how to debug multi threaded code.

Comment: I found also this trick on SO recently that allows easier STL debugging:

cd ~ \n
svn co svn://gcc.gnu.org/svn/gcc/trunk/libstdc++-v3/python \n
$ cat ~/.gdbinit \n
python \n
import sys n\
sys.path.insert(0, '/home/USERNAME/python/') \n
from libstdcxx.v6.printers import register_libstdcxx_printers \n
register_libstdcxx_printers (None) \n
end \n

(I'll make this an answer as it looks garbled in a comment)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried monodevelop? It can build and debug C code, Not show how it handles obj-c.

If you can get DDD working I have used that with good results on many strange platforms. DDD requires X11.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same experience with XCode, and ended up switching to Netbeans and Eclipse (still not sure which one I prefer over the other, both have strong and weak points).

This may seem an odd choice, but both of them offer nice C++ support, reasonable debugger integration, and good project management options. I enjoy the refactoring tools and the source version control integration as well. Mind that they are not as snappy and clean as Visual Studio 6.

As many others here, I do not like Objective-C, and am pretty much fed-up with having to learn different environment/frameworks for each platform I write for (I use Linux and OSX daily, Windows on occasion). Both Netbeans and Eclipse are a big plus for portability. They also support other languages that I use sometimes for smaller projects (Python comes to mind).

Comment: Thanks a ton! I already had Eclipse, so I just had to install the C/C++ package. However, the debugger can't handle 64-bit binaries. The problem appears to be the "binary parser," and looking online it seems I should have an option "Mach-O 64 parser" besides regular Mach-O. Do you know how I install this?

Comment: I do not know. Sorry. Because of my setup, I've only used it to develop 32-bit applications on OSX. I develop on OSX and then compile on Linux 64-bit for production, using a simple makefile.. sorry. If nothing else works, maybe you could debug in 32-bit and then compile in 64-bit the same way, just using a makefile? In any case, I would be interested in learning how to make Eclipse's debugger for C++ work with 64-bit apps on Snow Leopard. Please post if you find a way. Interesting question - and glad to learn I am not the only one that dislike XCode... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I add to what anon said that I found also this trick on SO recently that allows easier STL debugging:

```
$ cd ~
$ svn co svn://gcc.gnu.org/svn/gcc/trunk/libstdc++-v3/python
$ cat ~/.gdbinit
python
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/home/USERNAME/python/')
from libstdcxx.v6.printers import register_libstdcxx_printers
register_libstdcxx_printers (None)
end
```

Comment: Here's a one source of similar advice: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/295836/controlling-eclipse-cdt-debugger-output However, it looks like I'd have to upgrade GDB…

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered [cgdb](http://cgdb.sourceforge.net/), a curse based frontend for gdb. Maybe you'll want to give it a try, although it seems a bit outdated. (Jan'10)