# RTEMS Build failure for Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, gdb, rtems

I tried to build rsb for rtems in ubuntu 15.04 but gdb failed to install due to python.

`$python --version`

it is `Python 2.7.10`

I have also installed `$sudo apt-get install python-all-dev`

One solution I have found on SO is

[Unable to install GDB with python support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26910649/unable-to-install-gdb-with-python-support) I do not know How can integrate this solution with my problem. Any help would be appreciated.

**Error log for rtems:**

```
RTEMS Tools Project - Source Builder Error Report
     Build: error: building arm-rtems4.11-gdb-7.9-x86_64-linux-gnu-1
     Command Line: ../source-builder/sb-set-builder
    --prefix=/home/punit/development/rtems/4.11 4.11/rtems-arm
     Python: 2.7.10 (default, Aug  9 2015, 10:57:15) [GCC 4.9.2]
     https://github.com/RTEMS/rtems-source-builder.git/origin/eec82cd12621dbc6773a117e8de9ca0f1dc55043
     Linux punit-Compaq-420 3.19.0-33-generic #38-Ubuntu SMP Fri Nov 6
    18:18:12 UTC 2015 x86_64
    Tail of the build log:
    checking whether getsubopt is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether grantpt is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether initstate is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether initstate_r is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether mkdtemp is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether mkostemp is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether mkostemps is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether mkstemp is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether mkstemps is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether posix_openpt is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether ptsname is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether ptsname_r is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether random is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether random_r is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether realpath is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether rpmatch is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether setenv is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether setstate is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether setstate_r is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether srandom is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether srandom_r is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether strtod is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether strtoll is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether strtoull is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether unlockpt is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether unsetenv is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether strstr works in linear time... yes
    checking whether strstr works... (cached) yes
    checking for nlink_t... yes
    checking whether fchmodat is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether fstat is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether fstatat is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether futimens is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether lchmod is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether lstat is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether mkdirat is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether mkfifo is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether mkfifoat is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether mknod is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether mknodat is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether stat is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether utimensat is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether chdir is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether chown is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether dup is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether dup2 is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether dup3 is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether environ is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether euidaccess is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether faccessat is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether fchdir is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether fchownat is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether fdatasync is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether fsync is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether ftruncate is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether getcwd is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether getdomainname is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether getdtablesize is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether getgroups is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether gethostname is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether getlogin is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether getlogin_r is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether getpagesize is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether getusershell is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether setusershell is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether endusershell is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether group_member is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether isatty is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether lchown is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether link is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether linkat is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether lseek is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether pipe is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether pipe2 is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether pread is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether pwrite is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether readlink is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether readlinkat is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether rmdir is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether sethostname is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether sleep is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether symlink is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether symlinkat is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether ttyname_r is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether unlink is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether unlinkat is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether usleep is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether btowc is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether wctob is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether mbsinit is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether mbrtowc is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether mbrlen is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether mbsrtowcs is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether mbsnrtowcs is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether wcrtomb is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether wcsrtombs is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether wcsnrtombs is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether wcwidth is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether wmemchr is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether wmemcmp is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether wmemcpy is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether wmemmove is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether wmemset is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether wcslen is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether wcsnlen is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether wcscpy is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether wcpcpy is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether wcsncpy is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether wcpncpy is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether wcscat is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether wcsncat is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether wcscmp is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether wcsncmp is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether wcscasecmp is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether wcsncasecmp is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether wcscoll is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether wcsxfrm is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether wcsdup is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether wcschr is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether wcsrchr is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether wcscspn is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether wcsspn is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether wcspbrk is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether wcsstr is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether wcstok is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether wcswidth is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether iswcntrl works... yes
    checking for towlower... yes
    checking for wctype_t... yes
    checking for wctrans_t... yes
    checking whether wctype is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether iswctype is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether wctrans is declared without a macro... yes
    checking whether towctrans is declared without a macro... yes
    checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
    checking whether build environment is sane... yes
    checking for gawk... gawk
    checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
    checking for style of include used by make... GNU
    checking dependency style of /usr/bin/gcc -O2 -pipe
    -I/home/punit/development/rtems/rsb/rtems-source-builder/rtems/build/tmp/sb-punit/4.11/rtems-arm/home/punit/development/rtems/4.11/include...
    gcc3
    checking whether ln -s works... yes
    checking for x86_64-linux-gnu-ranlib... x86_64-linux-gnu-ranlib
    checking for x86_64-linux-gnu-ar... x86_64-linux-gnu-ar
    configure: updating cache ./config.cache
    configure: creating ./config.status
    config.status: creating Makefile
    config.status: creating import/Makefile
    config.status: creating config.h
    config.status: executing depfiles commands
    config.status: executing default commands
    checking whether NLS is requested... no
    checking whether makeinfo --split-size=5000000 supports @click... yes
    checking for default auto-load directory... $debugdir:$datadir/auto-load
    checking for default auto-load safe-path... $debugdir:$datadir/auto-load
    checking libunwind-ia64.h usability... no
    checking libunwind-ia64.h presence... no
    checking for libunwind-ia64.h... no
    checking for monstartup... yes
    checking for _mcleanup... yes
    checking for _etext... yes
    checking for etext... yes
    checking for gawk... gawk
    checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
    checking whether ln -s works... yes
    checking for x86_64-linux-gnu-ranlib... x86_64-linux-gnu-ranlib
    checking for bison... bison -y
    checking for x86_64-linux-gnu-ar... x86_64-linux-gnu-ar
    checking for x86_64-linux-gnu-dlltool... dlltool
    checking for x86_64-linux-gnu-windres... windres
    checking for main in -lm... yes
    checking for wctype... yes
    checking for library containing gethostbyname... none required
    checking for library containing socketpair... none required
    checking for library containing dlgetmodinfo... no
    checking for iconv... yes
    checking for iconv declaration... install-shextern size_t iconv
    (iconv_t cd, char * *inbuf, size_t *inbytesleft, char * *outbuf,
    size_t *outbytesleft);
    checking for library containing waddstr... -lncurses
    checking for library containing tgetent... none required
    checking size of unsigned long long... 8
    checking size of unsigned long... 8
    checking size of unsigned __int128... 16
    checking for library containing dlopen... (cached) -ldl
    checking whether to use expat... yes
    checking for ld used by GCC... x86_64-linux-gnu-ld
    checking if the linker (x86_64-linux-gnu-ld) is GNU ld... yes
    checking for shared library run path origin... done
    checking for libexpat... yes
    checking how to link with libexpat...
    /home/punit/development/rtems/rsb/rtems-source-builder/rtems/build/tmp/sb-punit/4.11/rtems-arm/home/punit/development/rtems/4.11/lib/libexpat.so
    -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/home/punit/development/rtems/rsb/rtems-source-builder/rtems/build/tmp/sb-punit/4.11/rtems-arm/home/punit/development/rtems/4.11/lib
    checking for XML_StopParser... yes
    checking whether to use python... yes
    checking for python... /usr/local/bin/python
    checking for python2.7... no
    configure: error: python is missing or unusable
    Makefile:8643: recipe for target 'configure-gdb' failed
    make[1]: *** [configure-gdb] Error 1
    make[1]: Leaving directory
    '/home/punit/development/rtems/rsb/rtems-source-builder/rtems/build/arm-rtems4.11-gdb-7.9-x86_64-linux-gnu-1/build'
    make: *** [all] Error 2
    Makefile:836: recipe for target 'all' failed
    shell cmd failed: /bin/sh -ex
    /home/punit/development/rtems/rsb/rtems-source-builder/rtems/build/arm-rtems4.11-gdb-7.9-x86_64-linux-gnu-1/doit
    error: building arm-rtems4.11-gdb-7.9-x86_64-linux-gnu-1
```

Answer (score 2):

For people who have the same problem, this is due to Python developement packet 
try this :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python2.7-dev
```

This should resolve the problem.

Comment: @fazkan Sure. But Its been long time I am just posting answer soon. Hope it will help you

Comment: @fazkan 
Try following :
$sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get build-dep binutils gcc g++ gdb unzip git
sudo apt-get install python2.7-dev